# Problems with deep linking to URL with AngularJS ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've just encountered a problem which seems to have occurred due to me changing the folder structure of my app (but I think this is a "red herring"). I have a small AngularJS application and to tidy things up I moved one section of functionality to its own folder. I updated all `<script>` tag references, all view `templateUrl` values in my `$stateProvider` section... I don't get an 404 errors, all controllers and views are loaded but I have noticed that in my app I can't directly link to a specific URL (I could before). The URL I wish to directly/deep link to is http://myapp.com/an/membership

When I type this into the browser I get a `GET http://myapp.com/an/membership/ 403 (Forbidden)` error. The route has 4 child states / urls. I can deep link to all these. To make things worse if I have a link in my app (using `ui-sref`) I can link to my state / url with no problems... here is my state / routing code... I have added some comments to explain my problem...

```
/* This is the parent state of my membership state !! */    
.state('sfm.in', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/an/',
  templateUrl: '/an/views/member-home/member-home-wrapper.html'
})
/* here the url is http://myapp.com/an/membership - I can link to it using ui-sref but can't deep link, I get a "403 forbidden", everything loads as expected (not sure if I need the abstract). */
      .state('sfm.in.membership', {
        url: 'membership', 
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership.html',
        controller: 'MembershipCtrl',
        abstract: true
      })
      /* this child state is a default and has the same URL as the parent - http://myapp.com/an/membership*/
      .state('sfm.in.membership.advantages', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-advantages.html'
      })
      /* No problem with deeplinking - http://myapp.com/an/membership/payment */
      .state('sfm.in.membership.payment', {
        url: '/payment',
        controller: 'MembershipPaymentCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-payment.html'
      })
      /* No problem with deeplinking http://myapp.com/an/membership/account */
      .state('sfm.in.membership.account', {
        url: '/account',
        controller: 'MembershipAccountCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-account.html'
      })
      /* No problem with deeplinking http://myapp.com/an/membership/data */
      .state('sfm.in.membership.data', {
        url: 'data',
        controller: 'MembershipDataCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-data.html'
      });
```

I have correctly set up the `$locationProvider.html5Mode` in my app (as I can deeplink, type the url in the browser for other URLS).

Can anyone see a problem here? *** UPDATE *** I have added the parent state in the routing example, please see my comment from the first answer!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot '/' in your first state:

```
.state('sfm.in.membership', {
    url: '/membership', 
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership.html',
    controller: 'MembershipCtrl',
    abstract: true
})
```

Comment: I originally thought that, however when I do add the forward slash the url 'http://myapp.com/an/membership/' doesn't work, but 'http://myapp.com/an//membership/' does?

Comment: where did you declare the state for : /an ??

Comment: I have just updated the example... The "an" route is added!

Comment: You must remove the last '/'. Try url: '/an'

Comment: With this, It must work:
.state('sfm.in', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/an',
  templateUrl: '/an/views/member-home/member-home-wrapper.html'
})
.state('sfm.in.membership', {
        url: '/membership', 
        templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership.html',
        controller: 'MembershipCtrl',
        abstract: true
      })
Always the same error? 403?

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange but I think the problem was the browser prepending the url when I type it in. I finally changed the code thus... but there is no real change here... I think the browser was the problem . In the meantime I changed the URL but cleaning the history / cache would have also solved the problem.

```
  .state('sfm.in.membership', {
    abstract: true,
    url: 'member-ship',
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership.html'
  })
  .state('sfm.in.membership.advantages', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-advantages.html'
  })
  .state('sfm.in.membership.payment', {
    url: '/payment',
    controller: 'MembershipPaymentCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-payment.html'
  })
  .state('sfm.in.membership.account', {
    url: '/account',
    controller: 'MembershipAccountCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-account.html'
  })
  .state('sfm.in.membership.data', {
    url: '/data',
    controller: 'MembershipDataCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/an/membership/views/membership-data.html'
  })
```